# (Android Fragments) How to prevent app from suspending when popping the only fragment on stack?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

I want the app to not react to the back press. Right not it suspends and leaves the screen, but doesn't actually close. I figure the app doesn't actually pop the only fragment because when you reopen it's back to that fragment, even though that fragment isn't the start destination. I'm using Kotlin by the way and the Navigation component so I'm letting it handle fragment transactions instead of doing it manually.

For school related purposes I'm too scared to post code in case they hunt me down for posting code, I just need the app to not close and I can't seem to find a discussion about this anywhere. I'm probably not wording it well when I search about it.